# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component, when adding Select in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a Select component in reactjs (from React95 library), however, it prompts me with a warning:
"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

However, I am not using a useEffect function.

I created my Select.js component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Select, Fieldset } from '@react95/core';

function SelectDrop(){
    return(
      <Select/>
    )
}

export default SelectDrop
```

And using it by just adding this to my Contact.js component:

```
<SelectDrop></SelectDrop>
```

If I use a button component, or any other component from the library, it works fine, but with Select, I get an error, and the page just wouldn't load

I'm trying to use React95 Library and using this as an example:
https://storybook.react95.io/?path=/story/select--default

Moreover, even if I don't add any options/labels/values etc. to the Select itself I still get this error just by adding the  component from the library, what problem could it be? My Contact.js file just has a couple of "divs" and that's it, I do not think that they are causing the problem.

Comment: Looking at [`@react95/core`](https://github.com/React95/React95/blob/master/packages/core/components/index.ts), I don't see the `Select` component in there - has it been removed?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even check the actual core, I thought that it will be there for sure, probably has been removed then I guess?